# Mahamrityunjaya mantra pronounciation

Tags: mantras, vedic-chanting

Can someone help me with proper pronunciation of Mahamrityunjaya mantra? I see different type of pronunciation on the internet. So what's the proper vedic chanting?

Comment: If it is just the pronunciation, read as it is written. Because in Sanskrit we read all the letters in a word.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZDuhp5o8Ybw